# Bing RouteOptimization doesnt have any effect on routeService.CalculateRoute

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

It seems that the `routeService.CalculateRoute(routeRequest)` does not take into effect the `routeRequest.Options`.  I have tried setting `RouteOptimization.MinimizeDistance` and `RouteOptimization.MinimizeTime;` and neither seem to adjust for the best route.  It seems that CalculateRoute always just calculates the waypoints depending on the order they are in the array of waypoints.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
            Waypoint[] waypoints = new Waypoint[waypointInfo.Count + 1]; // +1 for the store

            waypoints[0] = new Waypoint();
            waypoints[0].Description = "Store";
            waypoints[0].Location = new RouteService.Location();
            waypoints[0].Location.Latitude = store.Latitude;
            waypoints[0].Location.Longitude = store.Longitude;

            for (int i = 0; i < waypointInfo.Count; i++)
            {
                waypoints[i+1] = new Waypoint();
                waypoints[i + 1].Description = waypointInfo[i].Address+ " - " +waypointInfo[i].Name;
                waypoints[i+1].Location = new RouteService.Location();
                waypoints[i + 1].Location.Latitude = waypointInfo[i].locations.Latitude;
                waypoints[i + 1].Location.Longitude = waypointInfo[i].locations.Longitude;

            }



            RouteRequest routeRequest = new RouteRequest();
            routeRequest.Credentials = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Credentials();
            routeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = "BING API KEY";

            // You want minimum distance or minimum time?
            RouteOptions myROuteOptions = new RouteOptions();
            myROuteOptions.Mode = TravelMode.Driving;
            myROuteOptions.Optimization = RouteOptimization.MinimizeDistance;
            myROuteOptions.TrafficUsage = TrafficUsage.TrafficBasedTime;
            routeRequest.Options = myROuteOptions;

            //routeRequest.UserProfile = new UserProfile { DistanceUnit = RouteService.DistanceUnit.Kilometer };

            routeRequest.Waypoints = waypoints;

            // Make the calculate route request
            RouteServiceClient routeService = new RouteServiceClient();
            RouteResponse routeResponse = routeService.CalculateRoute(routeRequest);



            double dayDistance = 0;               
            directions.Clear();

            if (routeResponse.Result.Legs.Length > 0)
            {
                int instructionCount = 0;
                int legCount = 0;

                foreach (RouteLeg leg in routeResponse.Result.Legs)
                {

                    legCount++;
                    if (legCount > 1)
                    {
                        directions.Append(" " + "\n");
                    }

                    foreach (ItineraryItem item in leg.Itinerary)
                    {

                        instructionCount++;
                        directions.Append(string.Format("{0}. {1} {2}\n",
                            instructionCount, item.Summary.Distance, item.Text));
                        dayDistance += item.Summary.Distance;
                    }
                }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The waypoints` you used does EXACTLY what you said. They say to Bing, that the route should be exactly in this order. So it works perfectly and you're not doing anything wrong.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966873.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CalculateRoute will ever re-order the waypoints. RouteOptimization only affects which path is chosen between any two consecutive waypoints in the specified route.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you fix the points by which the route must pass, if you don't give excessive waypoints between "Start" and "End" you can see the difference in optimization.

I tried your code but it says I must pass an Endpoint as a parameter in :

```
RouteServiceClient routeService = new RouteServiceClient("Here");
```

Any idea how to fix this